# What is the job of remember keyword in jetpack compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want selectedProvince to be persist so i put it in remember, but whenever i change value in onClick, the framework recomposes and the variable is set to be listProvince.value[0] again (only for the first time). I thought it would be the last selected value.

```
@Composable
fun ProvinceDialog(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    listProvince: MutableState<List<ProvinceItem>>,
    onDisMiss: () -> Unit = {},
    onConfirm: (String) -> Unit = {}
) {
    val searchText = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var selectedProvince = remember { mutableStateOf(listProvince.value[0]) }
    Log.d("Test select", selectedProvince.toString())

    AlertDialog(
        modifier = modifier,
        title = {
            Text(text = "Province")
        },
        containerColor = EDSColors.white,
        text = {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(16.dp),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)

            ) {
                OutlinedTextField(
                    value = searchText.value,
                    onValueChange = {
                        searchText.value = it
                    },
                    leadingIcon = {
                        Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Search, contentDescription = null)
                    },
                    singleLine = true,
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(30),
                    colors = OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.colors(
                        cursorColor = EDSColors.primaryColor,
                        focusedBorderColor = EDSColors.primaryColor,
                        focusedLeadingIconColor = EDSColors.primaryColor,
                    ),
                )
                LazyColumn(
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
                ) {

                    listProvince.value.forEachIndexed { index, province ->
                        item {
                            FilterChip(
                                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                                selected = province.isSelected,
                                onClick = {
                                    val newList = listProvince.value.toMutableList()
                                    newList.forEach {
                                        it.isSelected = false
                                    }
                                    newList[index] =
                                        province.copy(isSelected = !province.isSelected)
                                    selectedProvince.value = newList[index]
                                    Log.d("Test select", selectedProvince.toString())
                                    listProvince.value = newList
                                },
                                label = {
                                    Text(
                                        province.provinceName, fontWeight = FontWeight.W300,
                                        maxLines = 1,
                                        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                                        modifier = Modifier
                                            .fillMaxWidth(.85f)
                                    )
                                },
                                trailingIcon = {
                                    if (province.isSelected)
                                        Icon(
                                            imageVector = Icons.Default.CheckCircle,
                                            contentDescription = null
                                        )
                                },
                                colors = FilterChipDefaults.filterChipColors(
                                    selectedContainerColor = EDSColors.greenCheck,
                                    selectedLabelColor = EDSColors.white,
                                    selectedTrailingIconColor = EDSColors.white
                                )
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        onDismissRequest = {
            onDisMiss()
        },
        confirmButton = {
            TextButton(onClick = {
                onConfirm(
                    selectedProvince.value.provinceName
                )
            }) {
                Text("Accept", color = EDSColors.primaryColor)
            }
        },
        dismissButton = {
            TextButton(
                onClick = {
                    onDisMiss()
                }
            ) {
                Text("Dismiss", color = EDSColors.notScheduleTextColor)
            }
        }
    )
}
```

I fixed it using mutableStateOf but i actually have no idea why it work.

Answer (score 0):

[`remember`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#remember(kotlin.Function0)): A value stored using `remember` will be saved across recompositions.

[`mutableStateOf`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#mutableStateOf(kotlin.Any,androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotMutationPolicy)): A value stored using `mutableStateOf` will trigger a recomposition when it is changed.

---

```
var myText by remember { "Hello" }
```

If you use `remember` without `mutableStateOf`, changes to the `myText` variable will not cause a recomposition. Jetpack Compose cannot detect when you changed the variable.

---

```
var myText by mutableStateOf("Hello")
```

If you use `mutableStateOf` without `remember`, Jetpack Compose will detect when you change the `myText` variable. However, during the recomposition, the `myText` variable will be reset to the initial value.

---

```
var myText by remember { mutableStateOf("Hello") }
```

If you use `remember` and `mutableStateOf`, Jetpack Compose will detect when you change the `myText` variable. It triggers a recomposition, and the new value of `myText` will be saved during the recomposition. The UI is updated correctly with the new value.

Comment: yes i understand this but my problem is i don't want to trigger recomposition when value changed, i just want it change so later i can use changed value. So i use remember to hold state but for some reason when it recompose and state is lost (only for the first recomposition).  For example if i write this:

var selectedProvince = remember { listProvince.value[0] }

Then later when i change selectedProvince it should save the changed value right? But it's not